# Postfix : how to redirect mail based on body?

Tags: email, filter, filtering, postfix-mta

I would like to change subject of messages based on body contents and recipient.

Example :
 * I would like that all emails for postmaster@mydomain.com gets their subject modified based on rules testing the contents of the message.

Is this possible and if yes how ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think [amavis](http://www.amavis.org/) can do this kind of things. You can create macros which will analyze emails and make arbitrary changes to the headers and body. I don't know exactly how this is done, though.